# Detect if any random object added in frame & keep track of them

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am really new to image processing. Currently I am using openCV for processing my video stream.

I am trying to detect if something was added in the frame & if added is there way to keep track of it. I already had tried to use yolo but It is not limited to some object I might have any random object coming in frame.

Secondly, I tried to use background subtraction method, but I have some object which keeps moving.

Thirdly, I tried to use contours but the are not that much accurate enough.

Please guide. I already had invested a month in this task. I have no clue what to do.

Comment: a video or images example of your case might help us

Comment: what do you mean by "something was added in the frame". Do you think of object detection appearing at some point in the stream of images or image edition (a video which has been modified after being captured)